# Plotting ternary graph with imported excel sheet

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, ggtern

I have a number of excel sheets (example attached) which plot simple ternary plots.[![basic excel sheet layout][![1]][1]][1]

This currently is used to plot a simple ternary plot of shape [![generated simple ternary plot in excel][![2]][2]][2]

left scale is c:a ratio, right is b:a ratio at base is (a-b)/(a-c) ratio

What I would LIKE to do is to be able to plot the shape of particles with their average size and lithology colour coded using ggtern.

I am NOT having a lot of fun with this to say the least

```
> library("readxl")
library("ggtern")

#data <- read_excel("my_file.xlsx")
Tdata <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\sedeal\\Desktop\\R_studio\\1770.xlsx", range = "Data entry!a1:F54", na = "")


Tdata = Tdata[-1,]
Tdata = Tdata[-1,]
Tdata = Tdata[-1,]
Tdata = Tdata[,-1]

colnames(Tdata)
names(Tdata)[3] <- "a.axis"
names(Tdata)[4] <- "b.axis"
names(Tdata)[5] <- "c.axis"
names(Tdata)[5] <- "lithology"
names(Tdata)[5] <- "roundness"

View(Tdata)
```

"seems" to get the data into R studio..
[![R data table][5]][5][![enter image description here][6]][6]

**PROBLEM 1:**
 `sapply(Tdata, typeof)`

a.axis      b.axis      c.axis   lithology   roundness
"character" "character" "character" "character" "character"

I can't work out how to change a.axis b-axis c.axis to numeric values

**PROBLEM 2:**
Do the "NA" fields mess things up?  They seem to in scatterplots

> Warning message: Removed 34 rows containing missing values
> (geom_point).

**PROBLEM 3:**
I need to work out the ratios c:a; b:a;  (a-b)/(a-c) and then plot these in such a way that I have a chance to mess with the formatting.

**PROBLEM 4:**
The biggest problem - I'm really pants at R-studio (so please accept apologies for what are probably really simple issues)

TABULATED DATA in the hope that it is helpful??

| a-axis | b-axis | c-axis | lithology | roundness |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11.11 | 10.98 | 5.92 | a-ig | sa |
| 8.57 | 8.27 | 6.2 | met | sa |
| 9.25 | 6.25 | 4.14 | ss | r |
| 8.21 | 7.23 | 5.03 | b-ig | sa |
| 8.34 | 6.18 | 3.28 | a-ig | r |
| 7.36 | 5.69 | 4.43 | ss | sr |
| 7.29 | 7.19 | 2.93 | ss | a |
| 7.25 | 5.29 | 4.89 | a-ig | sr |
| 7.95 | 5.16 | 4.46 | met | sa |
| 6.03 | 4.76 | 4.57 | a-ig | sa |
| 6.65 | 5.24 | 4.54 | qtz | va |
| 6.12 | 4.58 | 4.29 | b-ig | r |
| 7.43 | 4.11 | 3.29 | b-ig | a |
| 4.92 | 3.41 | 3.17 | ss | sa |
| 6.39 | 4.64 | 2.52 | a-ig | a |
| 5.12 | 4.99 | 3.31 | b-ig | a |

EDIT:

````
> dput(Tdata)```
structure(list(a.axis = c("11.11", "8.57", "9.25", "8.2100000000000009", 
"8.34", "7.36", "7.29", "7.25", "7.95", "6.03", "6.65", "6.12", 
"7.43", "4.92", "6.39", "5.12", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), b.axis = c("10.98", 
"8.27", "6.25", "7.23", "6.18", "5.69", "7.19", "5.29", "5.16", 
"4.76", "5.24", "4.58", "4.1100000000000003", "3.41", "4.6399999999999997", 
"4.99", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), c.axis = c("5.92", "6.2", "4.1399999999999997", 
"5.03", "3.28", "4.43", "2.93", "4.8899999999999997", "4.46", 
"4.57", "4.54", "4.29", "3.29", "3.17", "2.52", "3.31", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), lithology = c("a-ig", "met", "ss", "b-ig", "a-ig", "ss", "ss", 
"a-ig", "met", "a-ig", "qtz", "b-ig", "b-ig", "ss", "a-ig", "b-ig", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), roundness = c("sa", "sa", "Roundness", "sa", "Roundness", 
"sr", "a", "sr", "sa", "sa", "va", "Roundness", "a", "sa", "a", 
"a", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


The solution I'm working with (thanks to @SamR)

Tdata <- read.table(text = "a-axis  b-axis  c-axis  lithology   roundness
#COPY/PASTE EXCEL DATA INTO THIS SECTION

", header = T)

# Make numeric and calculate ratios

library(dplyr)
library(ggtern)


Tdata <- Tdata |>
    mutate(
        across(a.axis:c.axis, as.numeric),
        c_to_a = c.axis / a.axis,
        b_to_a = b.axis / a.axis,
        ab_ac = (a.axis - b.axis) / (a.axis - c.axis)
    )

#draw the plot


ggtern(data = Tdata, aes(x = c_to_a, y = ab_ac, z = b_to_a)) +
    geom_point() +
    xlab("c:a") + # replace default axis labels
    ylab("b:a") +
    zlab("(a-b)/(a-c)") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme_showarrows() +
    theme_anticlockwise()


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkFjy.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBobu.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvAmQ.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYFdJ.jpg
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eornO.jpg
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh6du.jpg
````

Comment: Liz, thank you for making great efforts to explain your problem.  As I see it, your problem is in two parts.  First, importing the data from your xlsx file, and second plotting it using `ggtern`.  We don't have access to your C: drive, so helping you with the import is going to be tricky as it stands.  Secondly, it would be helpful to see the output from `dput(Tdata)` in the body of your question.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) I will amend question with the requested info... I "think" the import is OK - as I can see the data from the sheet in R-studio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data you posted in the table.

```r
# Read in the data
Tdata <- read.table(text = "a-axis  b-axis  c-axis  lithology   roundness
11.11   10.98   5.92    a-ig    sa
8.57    8.27    6.2 met sa
9.25    6.25    4.14    ss  r
8.21    7.23    5.03    b-ig    sa
8.34    6.18    3.28    a-ig    r
7.36    5.69    4.43    ss  sr
7.29    7.19    2.93    ss  a
7.25    5.29    4.89    a-ig    sr
7.95    5.16    4.46    met sa
6.03    4.76    4.57    a-ig    sa
6.65    5.24    4.54    qtz va
6.12    4.58    4.29    b-ig    r
7.43    4.11    3.29    b-ig    a
4.92    3.41    3.17    ss  sa
6.39    4.64    2.52    a-ig    a
5.12    4.99    3.31    b-ig    a", header = T)

# Make numeric and calculate ratios

library(dplyr)
library(ggtern)


Tdata <- Tdata |>
    mutate(
        across(a.axis:c.axis, as.numeric),
        c_to_a = c.axis / a.axis,
        b_to_a = b.axis / a.axis,
        ab_ac = (a.axis - b.axis) / (a.axis - c.axis)
    )
```

Then it's just a question of drawing the plot:

```r
ggtern(data = Tdata, aes(x = c_to_a, y = ab_ac, z = b_to_a)) +
    geom_point() +
    xlab("c:a") + # replace default axis labels
    ylab("b:a") +
    zlab("(a-b)/(a-c)") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme_showarrows() +
    theme_anticlockwise()
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Added arrows to plot axes and switch the ratios (initially had a:c rather than c:a). I realise the plot does not look like the one in the question - I am not exactly sure why as your original one does not have axis labels so it is hard to see what the differences are.

Comment: When I do this it all works - when I try and do it from the excel sheet I get a sullen silence!  Going to save my script and try again with a fresh session :)  I'll update!

Comment: I tried running my code using the `dput` output you posted as input and it works for me. Does running the code using that output work for you? Or is the data you are reading from Excel different to the output you posted?

Comment: Can't get the upload to work from excel - BUT your solution works with a copy/paste from the sheet and to be fair that is a pragmatic solution that WORKS for now and lets me move forward... I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well in R-studio -

```
    # Load required packages
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggtern)

# Prompt user to select file
file <- file.choose()

# Read in data from selected file and sheet
data <- read_excel(file, sheet = "Data entry", range = "B4:F54")

# Rename columns for consistency
colnames(data) <- c("a.axis", "b.axis", "c.axis", "lithology", "roundness")

# Make numeric and calculate ratios
data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    across(a.axis:c.axis, as.numeric),
    c_to_a = c.axis / a.axis,
    b_to_a = b.axis / a.axis,
    ab_ac = (a.axis - b.axis) / (a.axis - c.axis)
  )

# Create ternary plot
p <- ggtern(data = data, aes(x = c_to_a, y = ab_ac, z = b_to_a)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = lithology, size = a.axis)) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits = c(1, 40), breaks = c(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(
    "a-ig" = "#F8D7DA",
    "b-ig" = "#555555",
    "met" = "#D8BFD8",
    "qtz" = "##D3D3D3",
    "ss" = "#FFA500",
    "ceramic" = "#FF0000"
  )) +
  xlab("c:a") +
  ylab("b:a") +
  zlab("(a-b)/(a-c)") +
  ggtitle(basename(file)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme_showarrows() +
  theme_anticlockwise()

# Save plot as .jpg file
ggsave(file.path("C:/Users/sedeal/Downloads/Temp", paste0(basename(file), ".jpg")), plot = p)
```

[image: generated plot]

Answer (score -1):

thanks to SamR

```
#setup
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("ggtern")

library("ggtern")


# Read in the data
# COPY AND PASTE THE DATA IN below the headings
Tdata <- read.table(text = "a-axis  b-axis  c-axis  lithology   roundness
11.11   10.98   5.92    a-ig    sa
8.57    8.27    6.2 met sa
9.25    6.25    4.14    ss  r
8.21    7.23    5.03    b-ig    sa
8.34    6.18    3.28    a-ig    r
7.36    5.69    4.43    ss  sr
7.29    7.19    2.93    ss  a
7.25    5.29    4.89    a-ig    sr
7.95    5.16    4.46    met sa
6.03    4.76    4.57    a-ig    sa
6.65    5.24    4.54    qtz va
6.12    4.58    4.29    b-ig    r
7.43    4.11    3.29    b-ig    a
4.92    3.41    3.17    ss  sa
6.39    4.64    2.52    a-ig    a
5.12    4.99    3.31    b-ig    a


", header = T)

# Make numeric and calculate ratios

library(dplyr)
library(ggtern)


Tdata <- Tdata |>
    mutate(
        across(a.axis:c.axis, as.numeric),
        c_to_a = c.axis / a.axis,
        b_to_a = b.axis / a.axis,
        ab_ac = (a.axis - b.axis) / (a.axis - c.axis)
    )

#draw the plot


ggtern(data = Tdata, aes(x = c_to_a, y = ab_ac, z = b_to_a)) +
    geom_point(aes( shape=lithology)) +
    xlab("c:a") + # replace default axis labels
    ylab("b:a") +
    zlab("(a-b)/(a-c)") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme_showarrows() +
    theme_anticlockwise()
```

[image: lithology shape plot]

Comment: Please do not copy the solution someone provided into an additional answer; instead upvote and accept the solution that solved your problem

Comment: I would if I knew how to :(